# Find the background position by mouse pos and its hit area

Tags: relations

I'm trying to creating a jQuery plugin where the user can interact with a div element background image.
Basically, the `background-image` is larger than `div` element container, so if the user move the mouse over the div element, the image is automatically scrolled to be seen completely.

[image]

I thought to do that by working with this relation, but it is imprecise.

```
mX : aW = bX(?) : bW
```

so

```
-((mX * bW) / aW) / 2 = bX
```

this does something near but it isn't precise, how can I find the right way to do the proportion?

Comment: imho this is rather a stackoverflow question

Comment: I thought to write the question here because I've asked about a mathematical relation first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going to give your "?" the name `X`. When `mX = 0`, you want `X = 0`. When `mX = aW`, you want `X = bW - aW`. So `mX : aW :: X : bW - aW`. Solving, we get `X = (bW - aW)*mX/aW`.

Comment: It works flawlessly